# Avoiding duplicates vs slow sub-query

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery, view

I have an MS SQL query which links to a table like below (12m rows) using the TransactionID. I need to sum the Cost but only when the AnalysisGroupID is in a given list, eg. (56, 62)

```
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| TransactionID | AnalysisGroupID | Cost  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1118850       | 57              | 5.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1118850       | 56              | 10.00 |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1118850       | 57              | 4.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1118850       | 56              | 7.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1132443       | 57              | 3.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1132443       | 56              | 8.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1132443       | 57              | 9.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145784       | 62              | 10.00 |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145784       | 63              | 5.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145784       | 62              | 4.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145784       | 63              | 7.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145786       | 62              | 9.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145786       | 63              | 8.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1145786       | 42              | 3.00  |
+---------------+-----------------+-------+
```

The problem is if i just do a straight up join on TransactionID i get duplicates because one TransactionID can have a Cost against multiple AnalysisGroupIDs.

However if i try to use a sub-query or create a view before hand like so:

```
create view SorDeliveryTransactionAnalysisCarriage

as

select
    sdta.transactionid,
    sum(sdta.Cost) as Cost
from
        SorDeliveryTransactionAnalysis sdta         
where
        sdta.AnalysisGroupID in (56, 62)
    and 
        sdta.Cost > 0
group by
    sdta.transactionid
```

...Performance is massively reduced, i'm guessing because all 12m rows of the table need to be summed before i can join on TransactionID in this case?

Is there anyway i can do my join(s) to avoid duplicates but without having to process every row in the table beforehand?

**Edit:**
 i should have mentioned a few specific points about my situation which helped me find a solution:

I need to run this query hundreds of times plugging in different IDs from other tables into other parts of the query, but importantly i only need to do this whole process periodically, i.e. once every week or two.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Filtered index to restrict rows

```
Select 
Transactionid,
sum(Case when analysisgroupid in (56,62) then cost else 0.00 end) as 'summ'
from
Yourtable
group by 
Transactionid
```

when you have a group by,SQL Will try to  get distinct values of the columns in group by and do rest of stuff

In your case,Unqiue idnex is not possible due to duplicates on transactionid,So create a filtered index on transactionid restricting analysyis groups like below..

```
create index nci_test
on dbo.yourtable(transactinid)
include(cost)
where analysusgroupid in(56,62)
```

Comment: Thanks, so do i run the "create index.." part as a command and then set the "select..." part as a view, and then link to that view on transaction id?

Comment: Create an index and try to run the select part and see the performance difference

Comment: Hi, this marginally increased my query time from 67 seconds to 60 seconds so thank you for the advice. I actually managed to find a solution which worked really well in my case, but only because i didn't explain the full nature of my problem in my question so that is my fault. I will post the answer i found.

Answer (score 0):

Because this only needs to be done once every week or two and doesn't need to continuously update with live data, the most efficient way to do it is:

1. Create the view as specified in the question.
2. Create a static table from the view like this:

Select * into MyTable from MyView

3. Reference the table in main Query rather than the view.

This solution means that the main work of summing 12m rows is only done once. Afterwards we can just reference the static table by linking on TransactionID